# What's wrong with my code - somethimes it generate proper EAN 8 somethimes not?

Tags: javascript

I have a generator that generates an 8-digit EAN code (with a specific prefix), but sometimes the checksum of this code is incorrect. Where is the error?

```js
function getean() {
  var prefix = "9625".split('')
  var randoms = prefix.concat(Math.random().toString().slice(2, 5).split(''));
  console.log(randoms);
  var checksum = 10 - randoms.map(function(letter, index) {
    return index % 2 != 0 ? parseInt(letter) * 3 : parseInt(letter);
  }).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }, 0) % 10;
  console.log(checksum);
  return randoms.join("") + checksum.toString();
}
var ean
do {
  ean = getean()
} while (ean.length === 9);

console.log(ean)
```

I tried to change my code but always results are the same - some EANs are good some are bad, I don't know why.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: By "some" are good are you refering to the ~10% of the time when the checksum is 10 and it ends up adding 2 digits, instead of 1? I'm not familiar with EAN, but I assume that in that case you want to wrap the checkSum calculation in `()` and the use `% 10`

Comment: When the checksum is '10' code is runing again so this is not the problem (this part is doing that "while (ean.length === 9)").

Comment: Sometimes results are like 96254941 but checksum is wrong it should be 3. I tried with other prefix (3 digit) and change slice (2, 6) but it won't help, that's not the problem.

Comment: It looks like your `index % 2 != 0` ternary is wrong, since the first element has index 0 and not 1, please check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into the EAN specification, it looks like the formula is `(10 - ((3 * Odd + Even) % 10 ]) % 10`, which means you're missing a `% 10`. Just make sure to use brackets when needed [check operator precedence here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table)

It also looks like you're getting the product of the even part instead of the odd.

Here is an answer:

```js
function getean() {
  var prefix = "9625".split("");
  var randoms = prefix.concat(Math.random().toString().slice(2, 5).split(""));
  var checksum = (10 - randoms.reduce(function(result, letter, index) {
    var isEven = index % 2;
    var letterNumber = parseInt(letter);
    var value = isEven ? letterNumber : 3 * letterNumber;
    return result + value;
  }, 0) % 10) % 10;
  return randoms.join("") + checksum.toString();
}

// get 10 codes
for (var index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
  console.log(getean());
}
```